# SDN Flow-modification attack

Tags: security, sdn

What are the steps that can be taken to prevent flow-modification attacks on an SDN controller? The attack would look as follows(As seen by the image):
[image]

Does OpenDaylight or any other controller have measures to prevent such an attack?

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

As with any network management or control scheme, you need to secure access to your SDN controller and between the controller and the hardware (authentication, dedicated VLAN, etc.). Of course, if your controller gets hijacked the attacker can do *anything*.

Comment: Are there any in-built security mechanisms in SDN controllers, such as OpenDayLight or Ryu to prevent this type of attack? To secure the controller being hijacked via an app through the northbound interface? I googled extensively but could not find a lot about flow-modification in SDN controllers.